# Software defined Persistent storage for DB clusters, kafka on k8s

Tags: cloud-storage

I'm setting up on-prem k8s cluster.

Want cluster to be self-contained to make it easy and cheap to replicate (minimum dependence on actual hardware, maximum software defined stuff, e.g. MetalLB)

Therefore, I need a way to provision PersistentVolumes backed by Highly Available storage.
My stateful workloads include SQL, NoSQL database clusters, Kafka cluster.

Here are some things I've found:

- Portworx

  - Promises enterprise ready k8s storage for databases, containers etc. Along with backup of everything. Sounds cool.
  - But what about pricing? Can anyone share their experience with using it as a storage provider?
  - Their seems to demolish other paid options (ScaleIO, Quobyte) in terms of K8s, is there any reason to look at them?
- GlusterFS

  - their documentation specifically implies that Gluster volume is not suitable for running SQL databases on it. Probably same goes for CephOS.
    But running VM (with its one file system) on gluster and DB on that VM will be okay. Can this be implemented and automated in k8s?
- Rook (rook.io)

  - I open source. As I understood, is not a storage provider, but a storage orchestrator.
  - Can Rook + Gluster (or sth else) an be a viable open source alternative to Portworx?

What do you use in your clusters? What can you say about the options?

Thank you for help!

### UPD

While it's quite lonely here, there is much more lively tread on reddit
https://www.reddit.com/r/kubernetes/comments/ijb0da/persistent_storage_for_db_clusters_kafka_on_k8s/